# React redux generated stateless components perfomance

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, typescript1.8

I am learning redux and react. And i decided to run a simple "stress test" with lets say 15k rows of generated component (i hope i did it right).

So i have stateless component which receive common prop for example 'year'. And i want to clone this stateless component over 9000 times and update them. For example change it prop(year) from 2016 to 2015.

I built this component in my testing project and it's working, but with slow response especially in IE 11. I am new to react+redux and maybe i did something wrong in my code.

As suggested in discord chat room i have added into my Page component:

```
    shouldComponentUpdate(nProps, nState) {
        return nProps.year != this.props.year;
      }
```

This did help a bit. But it is still slow.

Also as related question - Is it ok to use lodash.assign() to update my state? 
Also i am using typescript and it seems to have not built-in polyfill for Object.assign(); That's why i decided to try lodash.

So here is my top base component app.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as pageActions from '../actions/page';

import User from '../components/user/User';
import Page from '../components/page/Page';

class App extends React.Component<any, any> {

  render() {
    const { user, page } = this.props;
    const { setYear } = this.props.pageActions;

    return (
      <div>
        <User name={user.name} />
        <Page photos={page.photos} year={page.year} setYear={setYear} />
      </div>
    );
  };
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
    user: state.user, // (1)
    page: state.page // (2)
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    pageActions: bindActionCreators(pageActions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

And this is my page reducer:

```
import {assign} from 'lodash';


const INITIAL_STATE = {
  year: 2016,
  photos: []
};

function pageReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE,
                        action = {type: '', payload: null}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_YEAR':

    return assign({}, state, {year: action.payload});
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default pageReducer;
```

And Page component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {range} from 'lodash';

let StatelessSpan: React.StatelessComponent<any> = (props) => (
    <span>{props.year} </span>
);

class Page extends React.Component<any, any> {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  private onYearBtnClick = (e) => {
    this.props.setYear(+e.target.innerText);
  };
  shouldComponentUpdate(nProps, nState) {
    return nProps.year != this.props.year;
  }

  render() {
    const {year, photos} = this.props;

    let years = range(15000).map((value, index) => {
      if(index % 4===0){
        return <StatelessSpan key={index} year={year} />;
      }
      return <span key={index}>i am empty</span>
    });

    return <div>
      <p>
        <button onClick={this.onYearBtnClick}>2016</button>
        <button onClick={this.onYearBtnClick}>2015</button>
        <button onClick={this.onYearBtnClick}>2014</button>
      </p>
      {years}
    </div>;
  };
}

export default Page;
```

One told me that innerText is experimental and non-stable, so i've changed it to textContent. Still got delay in IE.

Comment: IMHO the exercise sounds arbitrary and impractical. What made you choose 15k rows? What level of responsiveness would you consider _good_? Maybe try [Chrome JS profiling](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling) to determine the performance bottleneck.

Comment: It may be sound arbitrary but I have a real application in angular when it may have 200 and more elements in Dom and can receive the same props, and not one prop like in this example, but 10+ props or more. And good level of responsiveness I think is below 50ms.

Comment: What happens if you swap out lodash's assign function with a different Object.assign implementation? Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-assign?

Comment: also, have you considered things like reselect? You may be getting too much re-rendering per action because of mapStateToProps. http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html

Comment: I have made next things: replaced _.assign() with ```state.merge(Immutable.fromJS({
        year: action.payload
      }));```
and creating initial state by converting it to Immutable.

Comment: @truedrog Please, can you share this file: ../actions/page'? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this discussion here: https://twitter.com/mweststrate/status/720177443521343488

So this partially answers my question about performance and gives good vision on how this both libraries behave with my case.

Answer (score 1):

React/Redux may be THE best way to write apps, but it's important to understand that elegancy can sometimes come at the cost of performance issues. Luckily, it's much easier to take an elegant solution and make it performant than the other way around.

I could throw a bunch of performance optimization tips at you for React and Redux, but you might be optimizing the wrong things. You need profile your app and find out performance issues you are running into.

You might find this talk extremely helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5sETJs2_jwo. Netflix has been able to start with very slow React and really make things go super fast without making a mess of things.

Comment: Well, i don't have 600mhz single core device, and i should rephrase my question.

Is it expected to see a lag performance when updating 10k simple spans with text inside, without any logic IN react? I build the same test in pure js, the bottleneck was Rendering on repainting and layot.

Now when i do the same in React my profiler shows me that react is doing some slow things(updating virtual dom maybe?). 
So, is it worthless to test react with such way?

Comment: If you'd like I could take a closer look at your code. Feel free to send me the complete example, and I'll do my best to see if I can shed some more light.